# What is a good way to deal with a very long column of buttons in a fluid web page?

Tags: buttons, layout, accessibility

So I have a fluid web page which will be used on both desktops and mobile devices.

If I put the long column of buttons (300+ buttons) on the side it looks great on desktop but looks ridiculous on mobile. If I make it so the buttons are in a long column on mobile it looks ok there but now it looks ridiculous on desktop.

What is a good way to do this?

EDIT: The top 5 buttons will be related to the most recent content and will be used the most frequently. However it does seem to be a good idea to initially hide the rest of the buttons and provide an option to dig deeper if the user wants. What would be a good way to have this option available but not overwhelm the user?

Comment: How are people using the buttons? What are they, and why are there so many?

Comment: I think your answer is "responsive web design"

Comment: If the purpose of the buttons is to show users different styles or designs, then I think the easiest way is to try and categorize then put in filters to limit what is shown. But if the buttons are meant to be the actions that users can trigger, then there is no sensible way of doing this as the user is just going to be overwhelmed with the information. This is the difference between scanning for specific information and browsing for general information.

Comment: 300+ buttons OMG even in mobile! someone's gone crazy. You have to super smart at this point.

Comment: You guys are providing some great ideas. Well, it seems the top 5 buttons will always be the most recent content and the rest of the buttons won't be used as often but should be accessible. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine both methods using media queries, so it looks good on desktop and good on mobile:

[image]

Comment: o my gosh you are amazig. Where are you? Which timezone? I see ur answers everywhere. Is it ur full time job ?

Comment: top 0.11% this quarter. you are killing every questions. what a massacre!

Comment: I updated my question with more information.